# Multiple slideshow.js instances in magento

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I have a problem regarding the stock jquery slideshow of RWD theme in magento 1.9.

I have to use 9 small slideshow and make them indepently working.
This is the custom code I've written

```
    <div class="slideshow-container">
<ul class="slideshow">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/1a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/1b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/1c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container">
<ul class="slideshow">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/2a.png'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/2b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/2c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container">
<ul class="slideshow">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/3a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/3b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/3c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container">
<ul class="slideshow">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/4a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/4b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/4c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container">
<ul class="slideshow">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/5a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/5b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/5c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container">
<ul class="slideshow">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/6a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/6b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/6c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container">
<ul class="slideshow">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/7a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/7b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/7c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container">
<ul class="slideshow">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/8a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/8b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/8c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container">
<ul class="slideshow">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/9a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/9b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/9c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

And the jquery code

```
$j(document).ready(function () {

        // ==============================================
        // UI Pattern - Slideshow
        // ==============================================

        $j('.slideshow-container .slideshow')
            .cycle({
                slides: '> li',
                pager: '.slideshow-pager',
                pagerTemplate: '<span class="pager-box"></span>',
                speed: 600,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                swipe: true,
                prev: '.slideshow-prev',
                next: '.slideshow-next',
                fx: 'scrollHorz'
            }).cycle('pause');
    });
```

All the rest of the code is untouched. The sliders are working well except for one thing. When I click on the next and prev buttons all sliders change image together. How could I solve this doing every slider change image independently?

Thanks for your help

Comment: add jquery code too..

Comment: sorry, there was but at the end of the same block of code :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <div class="slideshow-container">
<ul class="slideshow">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/1a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/1b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/1c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container">
<ul class="slideshow">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/2a.png'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/2b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/2c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container1">
<ul class="slideshow1">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/3a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/3b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/3c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev1">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next1">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container2">
<ul class="slideshow2">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/4a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/4b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/4c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev2">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next2">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container3">
<ul class="slideshow3">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/5a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/5b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/5c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev3">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next3">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container4">
<ul class="slideshow4">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/6a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/6b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/6c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev4">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next4">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container5">
<ul class="slideshow5">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/7a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/7b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/7c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev5">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next5">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container6">
<ul class="slideshow6">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/8a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/8b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/8c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev6">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next6">&nbsp;</span></div>
<div class="slideshow-container7">
<ul class="slideshow7">
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/9a.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/9b.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
<li><a href="linkhere"><img alt="" src="{{media url='homepage_banner/9c.jpg'}}" /></a></li>
</ul>
<span class="slideshow-prev7">&nbsp;</span> <span class="slideshow-next7">&nbsp;</span></div>
```

and jquery function

```
$j(document).ready(function () {

        // ==============================================
        // UI Pattern - Slideshow
        // ==============================================

        $j('.slideshow-container .slideshow')
            .cycle({
                slides: '> li',
                pager: '.slideshow-pager',
                pagerTemplate: '<span class="pager-box"></span>',
                speed: 600,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                swipe: true,
                prev: '.slideshow-prev',
                next: '.slideshow-next',
                fx: 'scrollHorz'
            }).cycle('pause');
        $j('.slideshow-container1 .slideshow1')
            .cycle({
                slides: '> li',
                pager: '.slideshow-pager',
                pagerTemplate: '<span class="pager-box"></span>',
                speed: 600,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                swipe: true,
                prev: '.slideshow-prev1',
                next: '.slideshow-next1',
                fx: 'scrollHorz'
            }).cycle('pause');
           $j('.slideshow-container2 .slideshow2')
            .cycle({
                slides: '> li',
                pager: '.slideshow-pager',
                pagerTemplate: '<span class="pager-box"></span>',
                speed: 600,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                swipe: true,
                prev: '.slideshow-prev2',
                next: '.slideshow-next2',
                fx: 'scrollHorz'
            }).cycle('pause');
            $j('.slideshow-container3 .slideshow3')
            .cycle({
                slides: '> li',
                pager: '.slideshow-pager',
                pagerTemplate: '<span class="pager-box"></span>',
                speed: 600,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                swipe: true,
                prev: '.slideshow-prev3',
                next: '.slideshow-next3',
                fx: 'scrollHorz'
            }).cycle('pause');
            $j('.slideshow-container4 .slideshow4')
            .cycle({
                slides: '> li',
                pager: '.slideshow-pager',
                pagerTemplate: '<span class="pager-box"></span>',
                speed: 600,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                swipe: true,
                prev: '.slideshow-prev4',
                next: '.slideshow-next4',
                fx: 'scrollHorz'
            }).cycle('pause');
            $j('.slideshow-container5 .slideshow5')
            .cycle({
                slides: '> li',
                pager: '.slideshow-pager',
                pagerTemplate: '<span class="pager-box"></span>',
                speed: 600,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                swipe: true,
                prev: '.slideshow-prev5',
                next: '.slideshow-next5',
                fx: 'scrollHorz'
            }).cycle('pause');
            $j('.slideshow-container6 .slideshow6')
            .cycle({
                slides: '> li',
                pager: '.slideshow-pager',
                pagerTemplate: '<span class="pager-box"></span>',
                speed: 600,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                swipe: true,
                prev: '.slideshow-prev6',
                next: '.slideshow-next6',
                fx: 'scrollHorz'
            }).cycle('pause');
            $j('.slideshow-container7 .slideshow7')
            .cycle({
                slides: '> li',
                pager: '.slideshow-pager',
                pagerTemplate: '<span class="pager-box"></span>',
                speed: 600,
                pauseOnHover: true,
                swipe: true,
                prev: '.slideshow-prev7',
                next: '.slideshow-next7',
                fx: 'scrollHorz'
            }).cycle('pause');
    });
```

Comment: Thanks, It works really well. I'd just to add the old classes to fit to the css but that wasn't in the question. Thanks again, have a nice day :)